# Return file path and context text line after recursive search

Tags: powershell, recursion, return-path

Trying to do a recursive search through all .txt files for a specific word and return the path of the file where the text was found and the context text line.

Currently using the below PowerShell script to recursively search and export to a separate file the paths of the files where the text was found and then open them to manually search for the context. The word might be found several times in file due to different context and all of them need to be reviewed.

```
$Path = Get-Location
$Text0 = "sometext"
$PathArray = @()
$Results0 = "$Path\$Text0.txt"

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory" } |
    ForEach-Object {
        if (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text0) {
            $PathArray += $_.FullName
            $PathArray += $_.FullName
        }
    }
Write-Host "Contents of ArrayPath:"
$PathArray | ForEach-Object {$_} | Out-File $Results0 -Append
```

I expect the output of "c:\folder\folder\folder\textfile.txt" (current output) to be "c:\folder\folder\folder\textfile.txt; This is the text line containing the context where sometext was found."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on PowerShell version 3.0 or better, you can do this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter "*.txt" -File -Recurse -Force |
    Select-String -Pattern $Text0 | 
    Select-Object Path, Line
```

For PowerShell below version 3.0:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter "*.txt" -Recurse -Force | 
    Where-Object { !$_.PsIsContainer } |
    Select-String -Pattern $Text0 | 
    Select-Object Path, Line, LineNumber
```

Would return something like

> ```
> Path                    Line 
> ----                    ---- 
> D:\test\blah.txt        this is the line that contains sometext.
> D:\test\anotherfile.txt sometext
> ```

Comment: Hi Theo, thank you for your help on this. It works well, thing is when working with long paths will generate only 119 characters per line ending the line with 3 dots "...". Have any idea how should be able to export full path and full text line skiping number of chars limitations per line (all these text files are located on very long paths...)? Thank you, Cosmin.

Comment: I am on PowerShell 5.1.15063.1805

Comment: @Cosmin The lines get truncated on console only. It is just the way PS formats it. If you were to add a  `| Export-Csv` cmdlet, you will see the lines complete.

Comment: The problem was I was using Out-File; Export-Csv works wonderfully. Thank you very much for your help, Theo!